# Unable to get messages on device when sent from XMPP server to FCM server

Tags: firebase, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to send messages from FCM console to my Android app. But when I send a message from my XMPP server to FCM server (targeting my device) messages are not received. My XMPP (my app server) connection to FCM is connected and authenticated.

Below is my final stanza which I send:

```
<message id='TdQnz-6'>

<gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
{
    "to":"eXPDcHdXhF4:APA91bGo .... ",

    "notification":{

        "body":"great match!",
        "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
        "icon":"myicon"
    }
}
</gcm>
</message>
```

Comment: What device are you targeting? Android or iOS?

Comment: I am targeting android and using smack 4 for xmpp client.

Comment: Are you receiving any requests back from the FCM server?

Comment: I have tried everything from connection verification to json payload syntax but nothing worked. Stuck for last 2 days.

Comment: Getting nothing back.

Comment: If you're not getting any response, most likely the request doesn't go through.

Comment: Ok. But the frustrating part is that everything seems to be correct. Connection is "connected" and "authenticated". Stanza namespace and payload etc are fine. Nothing is left behind - what should i do now?

Comment: Not sure if I need to configure something on FCM server for this or not. No such thing is mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Have you added the app in your Firebase Console?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Reverting back to smack 3 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dont put a Message id to XMPP, that wont work ! Put it to "data"!! You can Use "data" and add your own message id to it if necessary! The FCM Server generates an internal Message ID for you!

```
<message id="">
  <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
    { "data": {
      "score": "5x1",
      "time": "15:10"
    },
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
  }
  </gcm>
</message>
```

That part wont work as well!

```
"notification":{

        "body":"great match!",
        "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
        "icon":"myicon"
}
```

Leave it away and try to send ... check the reply from server

should be something like that

```
<message id="">
  <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
  {
      "from":"REGID",
      "message_id":"m-1366082849205"
      "message_type":"ack"
  }
  </gcm>
</message>
```

in case of an error you will get something like that

```
<message>
 <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
 {
   "message_type":"nack",
   "message_id":"msgId1",
   "from":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "error":"INVALID_JSON",
   "error_description":"InvalidJson: JSON_TYPE_ERROR : Field \"time_to_live\" must be a JSON java.lang.Number: abc"
 }
 </gcm>
</message>
```